# java class writing and object construction

Tags: java, arrays

This is a general question about writing java classes and how they're instantiated.

```
public class transaction
{
    int amount;
    char ref;
}
```

If a class is written like this then it can be used like a struct. Then when data comes over the network as a byte[] in a datagram it's converted into a transaction object. One place to do this is in a separate class, say like this:

```
public class doStuff
{
    static transaction t; // the int and the char are alloc'd onto the DataSegment

    public static transaction fromByte(byte[] buf)
    {
        t = new transaction(); // make sure t is null to begin with (on the heap)
        t.ref = ''; // initialise char (to avoid null bytes)

        t.amount = ByteBuffer.wrap(buf).getInt();
        t.ref = ByteBuffer.wrap(buf).getChar();

        return t;
    }
}
```

Then another class calls doStuff like so:

```
import doStuff;    

class otherClass extends Thread
{
    static transaction x = new transaction();

    ... in the run method
    x = doStuff.fromByte(buf);
    ...
}
```

But now I want to keep the class data and methods together in one place (supposedly like it should be?) so instead of having the fromByte(byte[] buf) method in the doStuff class it's moved to the transaction class. So the transaction class now looks like this:

```
public class transaction
{
    int amount;
    char ref;

    static transaction t;

    public static transaction fromByte(byte[] buf)
    {
        t = new transaction(); // make sure t is null to begin with
        t.ref = ''; // initialise char (to avoid null bytes)

        t.amount = ByteBuffer.wrap(buf).getInt();
        t.ref = ByteBuffer.wrap(buf).getChar();

        return t;
    }
}
```

Then in the otherClass I use:

```
import transaction;

class otherClass extends Thread
{
    static transaction x = new transaction();

    ... in the run method
    x = fromByte(buf);
    ...
}
```

and on the surface it all has the same effect as before.

My question is: Having added the operation `fromByte(byte[] buf)` on the transaction data (amount and ref) into the `transaction` class then the overhead to instantiate a `transaction` object changes. If there were hundreds of transactions per second coming from the network then adding the `fromByte(byte[] buf)` method to the `transaction` class means that when it's instantiated in the `doStuff` class there's going to be more overhead used than before. In other words instead of simply generating an `int` and a `char` (as a static variable on the data segment) each time the `doStuff` class generates `foo` then it's generated on the heap (i think, rather than the data segment) and further the `fromByte(buf)` method is pushed to the stack AND then the `transaction` class calls itself recursively on the data segment again (a static variable)...

well it seems a bit of a mess. is there a better way to put the data and method in the same class and retain maximum speed? can it get over the recursive variable call (the fromByte method returns a transaction object and that's ok in the 'int/char' form) any comment? :-)

Comment: Why does the overhead of creating a `transaction` change?

Comment: Do you mean to have `transaction t` as static?

Comment: well that's really the question... if you add a method to a class so there's data and method in the class then when the class is instantiated more stuff happens under the hood, right?

Comment: @SB yes, i want to use transaction t as static so it's only declared the once...

Comment: @rupweb but this way you will only have one transaction for your whole program, is this _really_ what you intend?

Comment: @fge yes... only one transaction address space, but it changes with each network packet... doesn't matter if transaction is lost, as in tv broadcast... just get the next one

Comment: Adding methods to a class does not increase the size of instances nor the speed with which they can be created and manipulated.

Comment: @HotLicks forgive my ignorance - why not?

Comment: You appear to misunderstand variable usage in Java.  Probably you should have neither of those `static Transaction` statements, particularly the first one.  And there's little sense in doing the `static Transaction x = new Transaction();` if you're subsequently going to create a new one with fromByte.

Comment: Why would adding a method change anything in the object instance?  The methods are attached to the `class`, which is pointed to from the object instance.  The `class` does get larger with each method, but the main part of the `class` -- the part that must be consulted to create an instance -- doesn't change much.

Comment: When you add methods to a class, nothing changes under the hood regarding class instance creation. The changes that do happen have to do with class loading and initialization, not instance creation.

Comment: @HotLicks ok so each method is pushed to the stack, no? (just means the stack pointer is adjusted) that's fine, but i am using the transaction class like a struct to hold certain types of data... other classes and other whole programs then use the transaction objects so i have to declare something! The fromByte(buf) simply returns a Transaction object so a Transaction object must be declared in the calling method no?

Comment: @Ted Hopp: thanks, so the more methods written into a class only affects class loading when the application is started up, and not when other classes create instances of the class or use the class methods...

Comment: Correct. When you create an instance of the class, only the instance (non-static) fields need space in the new object. No space is needed for any methods (instance or static) because those are associated with the class itself, not with each instance. For the same reason, no extra processing is involved in instance creation, regardless of the number of methods defined for the class.

Comment: and any new object is created on the heap... whereas static methods are pushed to the data segment

Comment: ... i mean static variables...

Comment: Simply put, a Java object instance is, at it's simplest, just a `struct` containing the instance (not `static`) fields, plus one more pointer to the `class` object for the instance's class.  (There are also fields used for locking and garbage collection, but they don't differ in structure from one object to the next.)  Virtual method calls are performed by fetching the `class` pointer from the object instance, then indexing into a table in the `class` object to fetch the specific method pointer of interest.

Comment: @HotLicks: thanks a lot... I wanted to know about the method pointers. Then about how the self-referential declaration works... in other words a class has a method in it to return itself (or at least a type that corresponds to the class instance fields)

Comment: It's all done with mirrors.  (A class has a lot of information it.  In fact, the "class" that the instance points to is not a `java.lang.Class` object, but an internal structure you can't access.  Inside it is a pointer to the relatively conventional `java.lang.Class` object, in case you ask for it with `getClass()`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will read from the start of the buf twice.

```
    t.amount = ByteBuffer.wrap(buf).getInt();
    t.ref = ByteBuffer.wrap(buf).getChar();
```

I suspect you meant

```
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(buf);
    t.amount = bb.getInt();
    t.ref = bb.getChar();
```

> Having added the operation fromByte(byte[] buf) on the transaction data (amount and ref) into the transaction class then the overhead to instantiate a transaction object changes.

Creating a `byte[]` and `ByteBuffer` each time is an overhead as well.

> In other words instead of simply generating an int and a char (as a static variable on the data segment) each time the doStuff class generates foo then it's generated on the heap (i think, rather than the data segment) and further the fromByte(buf) method is pushed to the stack AND then the transaction class calls itself recursively on the data segment again (a static variable)...

As mentioned, creating the `transaction` obejct is likely to be a small portion of your overhead.  E.g. reading from a Socket will take 100x longer at best.

> well it seems a bit of a mess. is there a better way to put the data and method in the same class and retain maximum speed?

Don't use `byte[]`, don't create a new `ByteBuffer` each time and don't create a new `transaction` object each time.  You can create these objects in advance or not at all and re-use them.

For example consider creating one *direct* ByteBuffer when the connection is establish (or recycle one) and decode the message and call a listener like

```
interface TransactionListener {
    public void onTransaction(int num, char status);
}
```

This way no object is created, on the stack or otherwise.

In this situation, your performance bottleneck will be reading from a Socket, depending on what you do with this information. ;)

Comment: thanks for your help... well I need a transaction object... (and many other types too) ... the byte[] is passed to the transaction object and then he ByteBuffer.wrap method unpacks it, no? If I have to use distributed system is there anything faster than reading from a socket?

Comment: Ok i have double checked and I am not finding that `t.amount = ByteBuffer.wrap(buf).getInt();
    t.ref = ByteBuffer.wrap(buf).getChar();` is reading from the start of the buf twice... from what i recall the getInt() method reads 4 bytes and then increments the position counter by 4 bytes well it's working like that ????!!!

Comment: i have to use byte[] because that's what get pushed through the network! ...an array of bytes... but yes, decode the message and call a listener is effectively what i am trying to accomplish. I am using the socket.read as the listener... then just doing stuff with the message

Comment: If you use `socket.read(ByteBuffer)` on a reused direct byte buffer, this won't create any objects and does a minimum of copying of data.

Comment: i am doing `socket.receive(packet)` where the packet is a DatagramPacket wrapping a byte[]... any comment?

Comment: You can do something like this http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-nio/datagram-channel.html but with `ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(nnn)`

Answer (score 1):

In terms of performance, the only difference between the two approaches is the cost of a call to the static method. This is a really trivial cost and is further reduced by JIT compilers.

In terms of encapsulation, the question is whether you want to put knowledge of the `transaction` class in the `doStuff` class or whether you want to put knowledge of the byte stream structure into the `transaction` class. There's an argument to be made either way.

Comment: and as Peter Lawrey says the bottleneck in the program is reading from the socket, not going to be other costs. My guess is that if the bytestream stuff relates only to the transaction data, then put it in the transaction class... but it seems to make a mess...